# What are the different GUI's available for Ethereum?

Tags: dapps, gui

Are there any easy to use GUI's for Ethereum?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the [Meteor DApp wallet](https://github.com/ethereum/meteor-dapp-wallet) which provides a decentralized app which allows you to manage accounts, simple wallets, multisignature wallets and smart contracts on top of an eth/geth node.

Currently, there are binary releases available by the mist browser developers who bundled them into a nice clickable executable, called "Ethereum Wallet". [Downloads here](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases).

[image: meteor dapp wallet]

Also, when you run [parity](http://parity.io) with the `--webapp` flag, you will get an interface on http://locahost:8080 for basic client statistics and an JSON interface:

[image]

In addition, there is the AlethZero C++ client, the so called *hardcore client*. (Not in the category *easy-to-use* but offers a GUI.)

[image: alethzero hardcore wallet]

The MIX IDE is targeted at developers of smart contracts, rather than end-users, it is also not easy to use, but it also allows you to interact with the blockchain by utilizing the GUI.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Mix DApp IDE](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Mix:-The-DApp-IDE), which provides a GUI IDE for developing DApps.

An overview was presented at DevCon1 in November, the video of which can be found on the Ethereum YouTube channel, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IABwhlibn0o).

Answer (score 0):

IDE is the leading development tool 
today, currently in private beta.

Can be seen as demo here: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbZjMFycSrs

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum Wallet (Mist) is currently in beta. https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases

Comment: The current Ethereum Wallet uses as basis Mist Browsers code base, which will be the Browser to use and run ethereum "DApps"